# subspace of Hilbert space is closed if and only if it is weakly closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Any hints for this question, thank you!

Prove that a subspace of Hilbert space is closed if and only if it is
weakly closed.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Hahn Banach theorem?

Comment: yes! will it be any help!

Answer (score 2):

Note that this result is true for any convex set, not just subspaces.
(Very loosely, you can think of the norm closure and weak closure as a primal and dual sort of thing.)

The norm closure of $C$ is the intersection of all norm closed sets containing $C$.

The weak closure of $C$ is the intersection of all weakly closed sets containing $C$.

Let $C$ be a convex set.
In general, since a weakly closed set is norm closed, we have
$C \subset \overline{C} \subset \overline{C}^w$ (the latter being the weak closure).

If $C = \overline{C}^w $, it follows immediately that $C$ is closed.

Now suppose $C = \overline{C} $ (the norm closure). Now suppose $y \notin C$ (note that $\{y\}$ is compact). The Hahn Banach theorem shows that there exists a continuous linear functional $\phi$ and some constant $\alpha$ such that $\phi(y) < \alpha < \phi(c) $ for all $c \in C$. Hence $W =\phi^{-1}([\alpha, \infty))$ is weakly closed, $y \notin W$ and $C \subset W$. Hence
$y \notin \overline{C}^w $. Hence $\overline{C}^w  \subset C$, hence they are equal.

**Addendum**: If you are dealing with linear subspaces of a Hilbert space, then there is a simpler approach (albeit the same idea, it is just that we can give an 'explicit' functional with relying directly on the Hahn Banach theorem):

It follows from the above that weak closed implies norm closed.

Suppose $V$ is a norm closed subspace. Then it has an orthogonal complement $V^\bot$. Again, from the above, it follows that
$V \subset \overline{V}^w$, the weak closure. Suppose $y \notin V$, then $y = v_0+w_0$, where $v_0 \in V, w_0 \in V^\bot$. Then $H=\{ x | \langle x, w_0 \rangle \le {1 \over 2} \|w_0\|^2 \}$ is a weakly closed set, and $V \subset H$ and $y \notin H$. Hence $y \notin \overline{V}^w$, and so $V = \overline{V}^w$, and the set is weakly closed.

Comment: Thank you, but I have a question: why do we need C to be convex?

Comment: Well, in the above proof, you need it to apply Hahn Banach. In general, let $C$ be the boundary of the unit ball. Then $C$ is norm closed, but the weak closure includes  the entire closed unit ball. Weak closed sets are not 'fine enough' in some sense.

Comment: Why is $H$ weakly closed?

Comment: @Lena The complement is weakly open. (Or the map $x \mapsto \langle x, w_0 \rangle$ is weakly continuous.)